# Memory Allocation for Threads and Processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

If I have a process, which has been allocated with some space in RAM. If the process  creates a thread (it has too, in fact), the thread will also need some space for its execution. Won't it?
So will it increase the size of the space which has been allocated to that process, or space for thread will be created somewhere else? IF Yes, where on RAM, need it to be contigious with the space that has been possessed by the process?

Comment: Yes, internal data structures used by the operating system take up space. The structures may or may not be contiguous. Either way, they are in the kernel address space and should be irrelevant to whatever horrid thing you are trying to do.

Comment: Calling 'pthread_create()' twice or thrice doesnt make a program horrid. Does it?

Comment: No, but needing to know where the memory is allocated and whether it is contiguous rings alarm bells in my head.

Comment: So I guess this is more of a general interest question, then? I was afraid you were trying to solve a different problem in the wrong way. People often do that on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'll be some overhead in the scheduler (in the kernel) somewhere since it needs to maintain information about the thread.

There'll also be some overhead in the process-specific area as well since you'll need a stack for each thread and you don't want to go putting stuff into the kernel-specific space when the user code needs to get at.

Answer (score 1):

All modern operating systems and for quite some time now, separate between the memory needed by a process and the memory physically allocated on the RAM.

The OS created a large virtual address space for each process. That address space is independent of how many threads are created inside each process.

In Windows for example, and for optimization reasons, part of that address space is reserved for OS and kernel libraries and is shared amongst all processes for efficiency.

The other part is dedicated to the application user code and libraries.

Once a process logistics and resources are created, the process now is ready to start and that will happen through starting the first thread in the process that will start executing the process main entry point.

For a thread to start execute, it needs a stack amongst other requirements. In Windows, the default size of that stack is about 1 MB. It means, if not changed, each thread will require about 1 MB of memory for its own housekeeping. (stack, TLS, etc....)

When the process needs memory to be allocated, the OS decides the how this memory is going to be allocated physically on the RAM. The process/ application does not see in physical RAM addresses. It only sees virtual addresses from the virtual space assigned to each process.

The OS uses a page file located on the disk to assist with memory requests in addition to the RAM. Less RAM means more pressure on the Page file. When the OS tries to find a piece of memory that's not in the RAM, it will try to find in the page file, and in this case they call it a page miss.

This topic is very extensive but tried to give an overview as much as I can.